# Sammy.js loading JSON from HTTP (Sinatra and MongoHQ)

Tags: json, jsonp, mustache, sammy.js

I'm testing Sammy.js from client-side, Sinatra for connect to MongoHQ and retrieve documents.  But, I've a problem with Sammy.js to retrieve it. My code looks like:

```
this.get('#/', function(context) {

  this.load('http://localhost:4567/test.json', { cache: false })
      .then(function(items) {
        context.items = items;
      })
      .partial('templates/index.ms');

});
```

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http:// localhost:4567/test.json. Origin http:// localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

What do you recommend to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I asked this question and why still not been answered.

```
this.get('#/', function(context) {

  context.load('http://...', { dataType: 'jsonp' })
      .then(function(items) {
        context.items = items;
      })
      .partial('templates/index.ms');

});
```

Just add the datatype to json padding.

Answer (score 1):

Your XMLHTTPRequest is getting blocked because of Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

To learn more you should check out the [wikipedia article on CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

To learn how to implement it on the server side check out [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org).

Unfortunately they don't have a Ruby version on enable-cors.org (I'm working on a pull request for this right now), in the mean time you can use something like this on any rack based server:

```
class CORSController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end

  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == "OPTIONS"
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end

end
```

Edit:

I should add that any class that inherits from CORSController will allow CORS requests, if you want CORS globally you should add this to your ApplicationController.

Also, setting *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* to a wildcard is a potential security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it setting the Passenger Module in Apache server, to run from http:// localhost/json/test.json. Thus, keeps the same domain "localhost" in this case and not need to have a constraint of type Cross Origin... Thanks! :D

**I learned: avoid use WEBrick**

Comment: Just note that you will probably run into this problem again once you deploy to production (clientside requests will still come from localhost)